Fiducial SLAM - Localization
I am trying to localize my UAV using the fiducial_slam node.
I am using this implemetation from Ubiquity :
https://github.com/UbiquityRobotics/fiducials
However, I am not very much able to grasp what is going on. Is the map transient ? Is it ever updating ? Or is it that I create it once and then carry out ArUco detection on the image feed. In which case, how do I localize my UAV ?
I have tried to understand, but found resources not expounding very well.
